# How to update drivers for a XPS 8700, and why do I hear a sound on the PC like a ventilator?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I would like to know what the best way is to update my drivers? My machine is a XPS 8700 Graphics card AMD Radeon.

And why after install of Ubuntu on this machine I hear a sound on the PC like a ventilator like it's running very hard? By the way this ventilator works fine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: @Pierre please refrain from editing closed questions which stand no chance of being re-opened. This will simply waste the time of reviewers when it gets on the reopen review queue.

Comment: @muru: oeps, sorry, I wasn't aware of that (didn't realize that). Will try to remember as you requested. I wonder however if anything like that is mentioned anywhere in help docu. Trying to become a "good" SE-citizen is hard, really hard! PS: similar suggestions for if they are not "closed" (or duplicate I guess)?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens oh, edit open questions all you want. Edit closed questions only if you feel they can be re-opened.

Comment: @nuru: ok as you suggested. Thx for teaching!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install networking drivers, and the best way to go about this is to connect to an Ethernet connection and install them manually.

You can go to Additional Drivers in your System Preferences.

But first, you'll need to install updates or your drivers won't be shown. To do this, perform the following command in the Terminal: `sudo apt-get update`.

And to answer your other question, that could be your optical drive. Just pop the Ubuntu LiveCD out when you're done.